Incircle and circumcircle
To draw an incircle we draw angle bisectors of each side and the point of concurrency is know as incenter.
The circle touches the triangle at 3 points and radius is perpendicular bisector of that side of the triangle
But for construction of circumcircle we extend the perpendicular bisector of the triangle and the point of concurrency is know as circumcenter . But isn't this point same as the center of incircle????
If I am wrong somewhere please correct me
(I am an online student so I cannot ask doubt from teachers)

Problem in second paragraph. Incircle is not perpendicular bisector in general.

@RobinSparrow can you please explain a bit more

@RobinSparrow every time I have done a problem incircle perpendicularly bisects the sides

the radius will be perpendicular, but might not land in the middle of the side

@tkw so when it does land on center the incenter and circumcenter are same points????

Draw them with GeoGebra (free) and see by yourself.

The best way to see that the centre of the incircle and the outcircle are different is in an obtuse triangle: the incircle (obviously) is located inside the triangle, so is its centre, but in an obtuse triangle, the centre of the outcircle is located outside of the triangle :-)

@DevPhalswal: I suggest making a habit of drawing clearly scalene triangles when you are working on problems, unless they are inappropriate to the problem. Various centers coincide in isosceles and especially equilateral triangles, which can deceive or confuse us into thinking definitions of those points coincide.

The incenter of a triangle is a point whose perpendicular distance from all the three sides of the triangle is the same, which happens to be the point of intersection of the three internal angular bisectors of the triangle.
The circumcenter of a triangle is the point whose distance from the three vertices is the same which happens to be the point of intersection of the perpendicular bisectors of the three sides of the triangle.
The perpendicular drawn from the incenter to any of the three sides may or may not bisect that side.
There is a cool formula that describes the relationship between the distance between incenter and the circumcenter(d), the inradius(r) and the circumradius(R) that states that: d^2 = R^2 - 2Rr. The incenter and the circumcenter will only coincide if and only if d = 0, which implies R = 2r (by using the formula) which is only possible when the triangle is equilateral(using trigonometry).
When you say that whenever you tried constructing the incircle, the radius of the incircle tangent to the sides bisected the sides, you must have been drawing an equilateral triangle. Try taking different lengths for each side of the triangle and check and see if you get the same results!

Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, e.g., basic help on mathjax notation, mathjax tutorial and quick reference, main meta site math tutorial and equation editing how-to.

Arsh is correct.  For polyhedra, in three dimensions, there are three measurements: the inradius is the distance from the center of a polyhedron to the center of each of its faces, the midradius is the distance from the center of the polyhedron to the midpoint of each of its edges, and the circumradius is the distance from the center of the polyhedron to each of its vertices.
